# iPhone keeps trying to iMessage someone who no longer has an iPhone

Tags: iphone, messages

My friend used to have an iPhone and we would talk via iMessage but when he switched to a droid it keeps trying to send him iMessages instead of SMS and the text messages take twice as long to send. How do I stop this from happening?

I deleted him from my contacts, restarted my phone, and even turned iMessaging off and on in my settings and nothing has worked.

Comment: This question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34216/how-to-disable-imessage-on-a-broken-iphone might have some info that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Does your friend still have his iPhone? He needs to put his SIM card in an iPhone with iOS 5, go to Messages in Settings and turn off iMessage - this should fix the problem instantaneously and for everybody who is experiencing the same problem as you.

(I have a friend who frequently turns off iMessage because she's worried about the data charges - I've had her switch it back on a couple times and the change takes effect instantly).

Someone on the apple forums was experiencing a similar issue and posted the following:

"I fixed the issue by putting my sim card back into another iOS5 phone and switched iMessage to "off" which effectively proves that it is tied to your number and not your Apple ID (in my case anyway).  I put my sim back into mu phone and the change was instant."

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3539877?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://supportprofile.apple.com/MySupportProfile.do, log in with her Apple ID, click on Edit products and click on the "x" to the right of the iPhone. Click Unregister.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://www.macworld.com/article/164479/2011/12/prevent_stolen_imessages_with_a_sim_pin.html) at Macworld offers a solution. Here is a quote from the article:

> Macworld can confirm that perhaps the easiest way to ensure that a
>   stolen phone stops receiving iMessages is to remotely wipe the phone,
>   and then call your carrier and instruct them to deactivate your old
>   SIM. The third and final step? Activate a new SIM in your new phone.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the answer for y'all, hope this helps........................................... http://sihuwa.wordpress.com/2013/01/14/how-to-stop-sending-imessage-texts-to-a-contact/

Comment: Instead of just merely providing a link, can you summarize the steps mentioned in the link?