# What can I do to stop imessage from engaging on a certain contact without an iphone?

Tags: iphone, contacts, messages

I have a friend who used to have an iphone but has since gotten another phone. When I go to text him it automatically does an imessage which fails. I've deleted him and re-added him. I've turned imessage off and it will work for a bit but eventually reverts back to imessage. What do I do to fix this?

Comment: Also, the answer here to contact Apple support might be a great solution to this dilemma. http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/130710/5472

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing. If your friend hasn't deactivated iMessage before he sold/lost his iPhone, then Apple still thinks that he has an iPhone and is using iMessage.

He has to deactivate iMessage. Here is the [Apple Support site](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts5185) for this.

> Bun in short: He has to [contact Apple Support](http://www.apple.com/support/contact/) to do this.

Or, when he/she still has his/her iPhone, then go to **Settings > Messages** and **switch off iMessage**.