# What is the API call that iPhone makes to check if a number has iMessage enabled

Tags: iphone, ios, network

I tried to sniff the http calls by setting up a proxy on my laptop in the same LAN as the iPhone. Once that was set up, I entered different numbers that I know have iMessage enabled into the number field of the Messages app, but couldn't see any calls being made.

Of course, the proxy was functional as I could see other calls go through such as Safari, App Store etc. Also, these numbers were not in my address book originally.

According to [How does iMessage know that the recipient is an iOS 5 device?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27274/how-does-imessage-know-that-the-recipient-is-an-ios-5-device) - iPhone makes a call to Apple servers to determine whether the recipient is an iOS 5 device or not.

What is this API call being made to see if a phone number has iMessage enabled?

Answer (score 3):

When checking whether a recipient is on iMessage or SMS, iOS does not use `http` protocol.

You can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) on PC or `tcpdump` on Mac to sniff the entire `tcp` protocol.